# git branch -f and git checkout in one step

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

Sometimes I need to move a branch to my current commit. There is two ways I can do it:

```
git checkout foo
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

I don't like this because this way I have to change the working directory twice. A better option is this:

```
git branch -f foo
git checkout foo
```

This is better, but I would like to do it in one step, just like when I switch to a new branch `git checkout -b`. Unfortunately, `git checkout -f -b foo` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alias methods are fine, but note that [`git checkout -B`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) does the same thing as a single atomic transaction:

> If `-B` is given, <new_branch> is created if it doesn't exist;
>    otherwise, it is reset. This is the transactional equivalent of
>
> ```
>     $ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
>     $ git checkout <branch>
> ```
>
> that is to say, the branch is not reset/created unless "git
>    checkout" is successful.

(It's not clear why this is specifically spelled `-B` rather than `-f -b`, but the point is that this *is* built in to `git checkout`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do as Scott Weldon suggests, by editing your Git config file to create an alias, but you can also add an alias with `git config`:

```
git config alias.branchout "! git branch -f $1; git checkout $1; true"
```

And then use it the same way:

```
git branchout foo
```

Note that you can always change the command name `branchout` to anything you want, to make it even shorter to type.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Alias. Add this to your Git config file:

```
[alias]
  branchout = "! git branch -f $1; git checkout $1; true"
```

Then use with:

```
git branchout foo
```